$false.length -eq 1. Why does it equal 5 when it's the value of an argument of a script?
We have:
$false.length
1

And:
$var = $false
$var.length
1

But:
param ([string]$var = $false)
$var.length
5

Why is that the case?

Because you specifically declared $var to be a string.
Use $var.getType() to see the datatype of your variable.
$false is boolean so if you assign it to a variable, powershell automatically declares that variable to be boolean as well.

+1, but might be worth explicitly mentioning that because of the [string] type declaration, the value being assigned to $var is the string value “False” which has 5 characters, hence $var.Length returns 5. A new Powershell user might not be able to read between the lines of your answer, so making it painfully obvious would be helpful :-).

I see. I wasn't thinking about what [string] means. I just copied the code elsewhere

You did cast $false as a [string].
This results into the value of $var becoming the string False.
Which is 5 characters long.
